# Как поставить атрибут для всех элементов с одним названием

Tags: jquery

У меня на странице есть множество элементов с одинаковым `id`, как мне поставить и потом убрать атрибут для всех одновременно? 
Ставится атрибут так - `$('#getinfo').prop('disabled',true);`, а потом снимаю этот атрибут вот так - `$('#getinfo').prop('disabled',false);`
Но такой вариант работает только для одного элемента, остальные не трогает, а нужно чтобы все имеющиеся на странице элементы с `id='getinfo'` попадали под изменение.

Comment: ID - это уникальное имя. У Вас никогда не должно быть несколько ID на странице. Если у Вас их несколько одинаковых - то скрипт никогда не будет работать как Вам хочется.

Comment: "все имеющиеся на странице элементы с id='getinfo'" Если что, то на странице может быть только один такой `id` потому он и называется уникальный

Comment: но скрипт то срабатывает нормально, просто у меня дополнительный атрибут есть, который и опознает какая кнопка именно нажат - <button id="getinfo" sid="<?=$row_info['id']?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Getinfo</button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id должны быть уникальны, используй классы, либо можно использовать теги и `.each()`
Пример:

```
$( "div" ).each(function() {
  //твоя функция
});
```

Answer (score 2):

id так и задумывался, что он должен быть уникальным на всю страницу.
Более грамотно будет искать по имени класса.

Впрочем, если нет возможности(или лень) все исправить [можно искать ноды по типу и наличию атрибута с любым значением](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
$( "div[id]" )
```

Но такой код лучше никому не показывать. В угол поставят. =3